# Alternative to list.count( ) in python

Tags: python

I am looking to be able to write an alternative code to the built in count in python:
This code works

```
def count(element,seq):
    """Counts how often an element occurs
    ...in a sequence"""
    mycount = seq.count(element)
    return mycount
```

but I would like to write it in a for loop (or  another way?), I've got this far:

```
def count(element,seq):
    """Counts how often an element occurs
    ...in a sequence"""
    for i in seq:
        if  element == seq:
            print i
```

I'm not sure how to return the re-occuring elements as an integer. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
def count(element,seq):
    """Counts how often an element occurs
    ...in a sequence"""
    count = 0
    for i in seq:
        if  element == i:
            count += 1
    return count
```

What this does: it loops over each item in `seq`, and if that item is equal to `element`, it adds `1` to `count` (which is initially `0`) and then returns `count` after the loop ends.

Using a for loop like this means that there is only ever one item of `seq` being referenced at a time, allowing you to scan *huge* sequences efficiently.

Comment: While we could all do a lot worse than following the style of the answers of @MartijnPieters, when I'm riffing off someone quite this closely, I usually say something like: "Mirroring Joe Smith:" to make it clear that the duplication is intentional and acknowledged.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sum()` and a generator expression:

```
def count(element,seq):
    """Counts how often an element occurs
    ...in a sequence"""
    return sum(1 for i in seq if i == element)
```

What this does: it loops over each item in `seq`, and if that item is equal to `element`, it generates a `1`, which `sum()` adds up to get the total count.

Using a generator expression like this means that there is only ever one item of `seq` being referenced at a time, allowing you to scan *huge* sequences efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way

```
from collections import Counter
def count(elem, seq):
    return Counter(seq)[elem]
```

And Just another way

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> len(list(compress(seq, [e == 1 for e in seq])))
3
```

with a little variation

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in compress(seq, [e == 1 for e in seq]))
3
```

another implementation using filter

```
>>> len(filter(None, [e == 1 for e in seq]))
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write it as a `for` loop, as per your example:

```
def count(element, sequence):
    c = 0
    for e in sequence:
        if e == element:
            c += 1
    return c
```